# Number to be multiplied to form a perfect cube

Tags: java

I wish to find the lowest integer 'y' which when multiplied to number 'x', 'x*y' should form a perfect cube. Here's what I have done.

```
boolean flag=false;
int i=1;
long y=0;
while(flag!=true){
  long abc= x*i 
  double apple = Math.cbrt(abc);
  int al = (int)apple;
  if(apple==al){
    flag=true;
    y=i;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Above code solves the purpose, but is there any better way to do this?

For example x=9 than y=3. /* y is least possible integer*/

Comment: Why you have tagged C++ and C when it's Java?

Comment: `y=x*x; /* x*y is a perfect cube */`

Comment: @Simz  just want the logic, I can implement that in Java, be it in any of the above languages, Thanks!

Comment: @pmg no! for example x=9, than y has to be 3. /* 27 is the least possible perfect cube*/

Comment: @sje397  no! for example x=9, than y has to be 3. /* 27 is the least possible perfect cube*/ –

Comment: @pmg  no your code fails for x =45 here y = 75

Comment: FIY: at the time I wrote my comment, there was no requirement for "least possible integer" in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the lowest perfect cube? Maybe something like this?

```
int y(int x) {
    int i = 1;
    while(i < MAX) {
       int n = i * i * i;
       if(n % x == 0) {
           return n / x;
       }
       i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(where `MAX` might be `Math.cbrt(INT_MAX)` and I assume `x > 1`)

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to decompose number into primes and then add primes that are needed to number have an whole number cube root.

For example if you have number `225`, you get `3^2`*`5^2` and you need power of that numbers devidable by `3` (to be a cube root), therefore you multiply it with `y=3^1*5^1`

If you have `32`, it is `2^5`, so you need to multiply it to have `2^6` because power of `6` is devidable by `3`

Having this output

```
for number 27 this is result map {} which means that y=1 and perfect cube is equal 27
for number 3 this is result map {3=2} which means that y=9 and perfect cube is equal 27
for number 15 this is result map {3=2, 5=2} which means that y=225 and perfect cube is equal 3375
for number 16 this is result map {2=2} which means that y=4 and perfect cube is equal 64
for number 17 this is result map {17=2} which means that y=289 and perfect cube is equal 4913
for number 32 this is result map {2=1} which means that y=2 and perfect cube is equal 64
for number 45 this is result map {3=1, 5=2} which means that y=75 and perfect cube is equal 3375
```

With this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map;
    int x;

    x = 27;
    map = perfectCube(x);
    System.out.println("for number " + x + " this is result map " + map + " which means that y=" + mapToInteger(map) + " and perfect cube is equal " + (mapToInteger(map)*x));

    x = 3;
    map = perfectCube(x);
    System.out.println("for number " + x + " this is result map " + map + " which means that y=" + mapToInteger(map) + " and perfect cube is equal " + (mapToInteger(map)*x));

    x = 15;
    map = perfectCube(x);
    System.out.println("for number " + x + " this is result map " + map + " which means that y=" + mapToInteger(map) + " and perfect cube is equal " + (mapToInteger(map)*x));

    x = 16;
    map = perfectCube(x);
    System.out.println("for number " + x + " this is result map " + map + " which means that y=" + mapToInteger(map) + " and perfect cube is equal " + (mapToInteger(map)*x));

    x = 17;
    map = perfectCube(x);
    System.out.println("for number " + x + " this is result map " + map + " which means that y=" + mapToInteger(map) + " and perfect cube is equal " + (mapToInteger(map)*x));

    x = 32;
    map = perfectCube(x);
    System.out.println("for number " + x + " this is result map " + map + " which means that y=" + mapToInteger(map) + " and perfect cube is equal " + (mapToInteger(map)*x));

    x = 45;
    map = perfectCube(x);
    System.out.println("for number " + x + " this is result map " + map + " which means that y=" + mapToInteger(map) + " and perfect cube is equal " + (mapToInteger(map)*x));

}

private static int mapToInteger(Map<Integer, Integer> map){
    int x=1;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        x*= Math.pow(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return x;
}

private static Map<Integer, Integer> perfectCube(int x) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = mapPrimes(x);
    Map<Integer, Integer> mapY = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if ( (entry.getValue()+1)/3.0 == (entry.getValue()+1)/3){
            mapY.put(entry.getKey(), 1);
        } else if ( (entry.getValue()+2)/3.0 == (entry.getValue()+2)/3){
            mapY.put(entry.getKey(),2);
        }
    }

    return mapY;
}


public static Map<Integer, Integer> mapPrimes(int numbers) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> primes = primeFactors(numbers);
    for (Integer prime : primes) {
        if (map.containsKey(prime)) {
            int value = map.get(prime);
            map.put(prime, value + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(prime, 1);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

public static List<Integer> primeFactors(int numbers) {
    int n = numbers;
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        factors.add(n);
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm too lazy to check - but does it give y = 75 for x = 45?

Comment: Cool. Is it faster than mine? :)

Comment: @sje397 - for huge numbers it surely does.